# Who is considered wise hearted?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, vayakhel

In Exodus 35:10,

> And every wise hearted person among you shall come and make everything that the Lord has commanded:

Moses, in the Name of Hashem, calls forth every "wise hearted" person to gather the contributions in order to construct the Mishkan and its components.

Rashi to Exodus 35:5 says this about generous-hearted people

> Since his heart moved him to generosity, he is called “generous-hearted” (נְדִיב לֵב).

- What is the connection between wisdom and the heart in terms of construction?
- Who would be qualified to construct the Mishkan?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but the Haamek Davar writes, "All those who are wise in heart: This included not only scholars but all who feared Heaven. If they would come to participate in the making of the Tabernacle, Hashem would assist them even if they had never learned a skilled craft prior to this."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rambam in his [Moreh Nevuchim (3:54:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.54.1?ven=Guide_for_the_Perplexed,_English_Translation,_Friedlander_(1903)&vhe=Moreh_Nevuchim,_translated_by_Ibn_Tibon&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> The expression ḥokmah denotes also knowledge of any workmanship. Comp. "And every wise-hearted among you shall come and make all that the Lord hath commanded" (Exod. 35:10);" And all the women that were wise-hearted did spin" (ibid. ver. 25).

Rav Moshe Feinstein (Darash Moshe al HaTorah, p. 151 ArtScroll) seems to explain that in first instance, it was Bezalel who was gifted by Hashem with the "chochma" to be the foremost artisan on the project, however, if anyone would have this ability, he would be instructed to also participate. The reason for this, Rav Feinstein explains, is that if Bezalel failed to make any of the portion of the Mishkan by himself, all the others would have to take it over and help.

This is what the Rambam means with that the expression chochmah also denotes knowledge of any workmanship. It was in first instance Bezalel who got this chochma by Hashem, but this was not the chochma Ben Zoma in Avot 4:1 is talking about. G-d says [(Shemos 31:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.2?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> I have endowed him with a divine spirit of skill, ability, and knowledge in every kind of craft;

This is why the [Targum Yonathan](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.3?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Exodus&lang2=en) translates this pasuk as:

> and have fulfilled him with the Spirit of holiness from before the Lord, in wisdom and in intelligence, in knowledge, **and in all workmanship**;

So, according to the insights of the Rambam and Rav Moshe Feinstein, everyone who had knowledge of any workmanship and was able to construct things, was, besides Bezalel, also instructed to help building the Mikdash.

This can be found in the pasuk in [Shemos 36:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.36.1?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Let, then, Bezalel and Oholiab **and all the skilled persons** whom the LORD has endowed with skill and ability to perform expertly all the tasks connected with the service of the sanctuary carry out all that the LORD has commanded.

It writes, "and all the skilled persons, whom the L-rd has endowed with skill [...]".